# How to remove table row "If that table cell not contains values in an array"?

Tags: jquery

This is my example code:

My array is:

```
var myarray = ["air india", "king fisher", "Go Air"];
```

and my table is:

```
                <table>
                    <tr>
                       <td>air india</td>
                       <td>code:121</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>Indiago</td>
                       <td>code:325</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Now, i want to remove the rows which not contains values in the array 'myarray'. In this case i need to remove second row(Indiago is not in myarray).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var myarray = ["air india", "king fisher", "Go Air"];
    $('table td:first-child').each(function(index,Element){
        var tdValue=$(Element).text();
        if($.inArray(tdValue,myarray)){
            $(Element).closest('tr').remove();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

loop through all rows, read the text of the first `td` in each row, check whether it is in the array, if not --> remove the row (referenced by `this` because you are loop through the rows)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some links for you:

- Loop through all table rows with [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) element from DOM
- Get [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) of current element

Please, please read the docs first and produce some code of your own. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = ["air india", "king fisher", "Go Air"];

$('table tr').each(function() {
    var td = $('> td:first', this);
    if($.inArray(td.text(), myArray) == -1) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/y8CLA/1/

Comment: Out of interest, what's the advantage to defining your own inArray over using the existing jQuery one?

Comment: @Hearaman: Then please accept and maybe +1. toukasomething: none. didn't know about it. edited the answer.